# MySQL - One to Many Relationship does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, relationship

I have 2 tables, one for the Employees and another for the Departments. A department can have multiple employees but one employee may only work in one Department. Their relationship is [1:many].

I am trying to do it in MySQL, but I encounter an issue. If I have 8 different departments and I try to add more than 8 employees in total, who work in different departments, I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
```

If I have 8 or less employees, everything works great. Upon adding a 9th employee, I get the above error.

**Department Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS department(
    id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Department Inserts:**

```
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Athens');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Patras');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Kalamata');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Heraklion');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Thessaloniki');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Xanthi');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Larisa');
INSERT INTO department(name) VALUES ('Alexandroupoli');
```

**Employee Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
    id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    born INT(20) NOT NULL, 
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    department_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) references department(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Employee Inserts:**

```
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Vaggelis','Michos','vagg7@gmail.com','1995','Greece','Athens');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('James','Gunn','james8@gmail.com','1970','USA','Athens');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('George','McMahon','george95@gmail.com','1978','Usa','Patras');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('John','Jones','john13@gmail.com','1992','England','Patras');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Marinos','Kuriakopoulos','marin_kur@gmail.com','1986','Greece','Alexandroupoli');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Dimitris','Nikolaou','dimitis8@yahoo.gr','1984','Greece','Larisa');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Soufiane','El Kaddouri','sofiane@yahoo.com','1974','France','Xanthi');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Maria','Apostolou','mariamaria1@gmail.com','1997','Greece','Larisa');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Ioannis','Marinou','ioannis_ap@yahoo.gr','1982','Greece','Kalamata');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Thanasis','Athanasiou','thanos89@gmail.com','1989','Cyprus','Heraklion');
```

This is what it looks like after the CREATE-INSERT operations:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, at the 9th insertion in Employees table, the insertion fails and I get the error I described, which is:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key back to departments was set to id which in the employees table is the employee_id;  it needs to reference the department_id.  I added department_id to your employee table and changed the foreign key reference to department_id.  I removed department_name as it would be redundant data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
    id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    born INT(20) NOT NULL, 
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    department_id INT(20)
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) references department(id)
```

)ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: At the employee insertions, I would need to give to the department_id the same id I gave in the department insertions?

Comment: @ceid-vg  Yes, the department_id used when inserting employees matches the ID in the department table for the department the employee works for.  When you want to display the department name with the employee, join the two tables.  I agree with Jacques that the IDs are best named as dept_id and emp_id to make your code more human readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong field in the foreign key for `employee`. For clarity, you should name each `id` field differently.
`dept_id` and `employee_id`
Then the `employee` table should have a field called `dept_id` (not department_name) which will validate against `department`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS department(
  dept_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
  empl_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  born INT(20) NOT NULL, 
  country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  dept_id INT(20) NOT NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) references department(dept_id)
```

)ENGINE=INNODB;

You can then get the `department_name` through a JOIN